# How to escape single quote in appleScript/shell?

Tags: bash, shell, applescript

I have looked at this topic: [single quote escaping in applescript/shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28358317/single-quote-escaping-in-applescript-shell) Although it was helpful, it does not quite solve my problem. This AppleScript snippet illustrates the problem:

```
set lastName to "O'Donnell"
set lastScript to "/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy /Users/david/.name.plist -c 'Set Last '" & quoted form of (lastName & "'")
display dialog lastScript
do shell script lastScript
```

The property list file ".name.plist" in my home folder contains a key 'Last' to store the name 'O'Donnell'. The variable lastScript is passed as:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy /Users/david/.name.plist -c 'Set Last ''O'\''Donnell'\'''
```

The script executes, but 'Last' is set to 'ODonnell' without the vital apostrophe. This is demonstrated by running this command in the shell:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy /Users/david/.name.plist -c 'Print Last'
```

PlistBuddy can be run in interactive mode:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy /Users/david/.name.plist
```

The command:

```
'Set Last O\'Donnell'
```

successfully saves the name. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've already answered you question, The only way to include a double quote is to escape it.

Comment: I tested your script and it seemed to work, i just `display dialog`ed the quoted part, then echoed it in terminal, and it works

Answer (score 1):

Your escaping is messed up. Put the text value in double quotes to keep PlistBuddy happy, then single-quote the entire -c argument to keep bash happy:

```
to escapeDoubleQuotes(txt)
  set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "\\"
  set lst to txt's text items
  set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "\\\\"
  set txt to lst as text
  set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "\""
  set lst to txt's text items
  set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "\\\""
  return lst as text
end escapeDoubleQuotes

set lastName to "O'Donnell"

"/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy /Users/david/.name.plist -c " & quoted form of ("Set Last " & escapeDoubleQuotes(lastName))

--> "/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy /Users/david/.name.plist -c 'Set Last \"O'\\''Donnell\"'"
```

Comment: I'm trying this approach but instead of returning `O'\\''Donnell`, it returns `O'\''Donnell`.

[Context: I'm trying to escape an apostrophe/single quote from an AppleScript variable that I'm trying to send to bash to form an CSV file with awk.]

Any ideas?